# R: What is the working directory when executing covr?

Tags: r, json, covr

I'm working on a project, where I load a json file. By default, I start the project at the root of the project, however when testing, the path changes. Therefore I included the following statement:

```
if (grepl("testthat", getwd())) {
    template <- jsonlite::read_json("../../templates/initial_status.json")
  }else{
    template <- jsonlite::read_json("./templates/initial_status.json")
  }
```

This works, however, when using `covr::gitlab()` the file cannot be opened. I guess the working directory changed and therefore the file is not found:

```
Error in `open.connection(con, "rb")`: kann Verbindung nicht öffnen
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-MyPackage::api_create(...) at test-API.R:40:2
 2.   \-MyPackage:::get_initial_status(initial_status)
 3.     \-jsonlite::read_json("../../templates/initial_status.json")
```

Of course a working around is to use `setwd(...)` however I don't like this, because I want to publish the package and therefore user may place the package in different locations.

What's the best solution here?

Comment: Maybe this is why people prefer `here::here()`, but I don't know exactly.

Comment: hey thnak for the tip! I now use `path <- here("templates", "initial_status.json")
  template <- jsonlite::read_json(path)`. while this is working for testing, `covr` still fails with the same error message :/

Comment: is this project open source? link to the repo?

Comment: no can't publish in the moment but it's planned

Comment: Put a `debugonce(jsonlite::read_json)` and see what happens..

Comment: does not change anything. should this print something?

Comment: seems like `covr` set workspace to s.th. like `C:/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWCdAqq/R_LIBS43b46f466da2/MyPackage` which does only include test folder...

Comment: Alright; Try to use the `inst` folder in an R-package, i.e. [this](https://r-pkgs.org/inst.html)

Comment: It is meant to be the folder of stuff that has to be there, without being manipulated or removed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to execute from a random temporary directory like this:
"/private/var/folders/wr/_qxy_jbd2kg1t72cr7d89_jc0000gn/T/RtmptlUqd8/R_LIBS171fb7c114d3c/pkg_name/pkg_name-tests/testthat"

I stumbled upon this because it quite un-intuitively makes tests fail which do not fail in context if they rely on something with a path (e.g. a call to load in global variables from a file, etc.)

I just tried this by adding a test like:

```
test_that("working_dir", {expect_identical(getwd(), "working_dir")})
```

and upon running `covr::package_coverage()` got:

```
══ Failed tests ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
── Failure ('test-stuff.R:18:20'): working_dir ────────────────────────────────────────
getwd() (`actual`) not identical to "working_dir" (`expected`).

actual vs expected
- "/private/var/folders/wr/_qxy_jbd2kg1t72cr7d89_jc0000gn/T/RtmptlUqd8/R_LIBS171fb7c114d3c/pkg_name/pkg_name-tests/testthat"
+ "working_dir"
```

Echoing `here::here()` instead will return something like `/private/var/folders/wr/_qxy_jbd2kg1t72cr7d89_jc0000gn/T/RtmptlUqd8/R_LIBS171fb7c114d3c/pkg_name` so I assume it copies the package directory in entirety somewhere and maybe it can help you.

Unfortunately it doesn't help at all if you rely on resources in a folder above your package folder.